# Fastest way to randomly delete a lot of rows in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I've made the grave mistake of using Postgres as a time series database and it's beginning to get quite slow.  Right now I have 30 million rows in each table.

So this question has been answered here, but the issue is that it scales very poorly for large sets of data.

> [Best way to delete large no of random rows in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429588/best-way-to-delete-large-no-of-random-rows-in-postgresql)

Using this method it takes 5 minutes to delete half a million rows.  Even locking the table adds nothing to the performance.

The example explain for this query:

```
explain delete from interest_rate_set where ctid = ANY(ARRAY(
        select ctid from interest_rate_set TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(50)
    ));
```

```
Delete on interest_rate_set  (cost=790996.71..791036.81 rows=10 width=6)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Sample Scan on interest_rate_set interest_rate_set_1  (cost=0.00..790996.70 rows=15012470 width=6)
          Sampling: bernoulli ('50'::real)
  ->  Tid Scan on interest_rate_set  (cost=0.01..40.11 rows=10 width=6)
        TID Cond: (ctid = ANY ($0))
```

I've tried running this before, but I don't feel like it linearly scales.  I'd expect it to take ~3 hours.  But my connection times out before then so I've never been able to run it.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Instead of aggregating all those IDs into an array, try `where ctid in (select ... tablesample)`. But deleting 50% of a table will take some time, there is not much you can do. It's probably faster to create a new table (` create table ... as select ...`) with the rows you want to keep.

Comment: 1) Why delete randomly from a time series? That would seem to undermine the purpose of a time series. 2) Why `ctid` and not the `Primary Key` field?